# Django Queryset Filter by number of objects in related set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model with a related set, something like follows:

```
class User(models.Model):
    '''other stuff'''

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('app.User')
    chat = models.ForeignKey('app.Chat') # Refers to Chat model below.

class Chat(models.Model):
''' other stuff'''...
```

So when I want to filter my Chats by existence of some message sent by some user within for example, I use something like:

```
usr = User.objects.filter(pk=123)
chats = Chat.objects.filter(message__user=usr)
```

That's fine and dandy, but I want to filter by whether a chat contains a certain minimum number of messages (Eg. min. 3 messages in the chat). Ideally I want to use just the .filter function, without going through annotate.

EDIT: I want to make a call within the .filter function, something like

```
Chat.objects.filter(message__<count>__gte=3) # This doesn't work
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you want to count without the count?

Comment: I want to filter my chats by the number of messages related to them.

Comment: use  Chat.message_set.count() > 3

Comment: I want to do this within the filter function ideally to reduce DB impact. Updating my question to include this.

Comment: For that you can use `annotate` or `aggregate`. it will not affect you db

Comment: @luxcem the main idea of the OP is do query without annotation )

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: If annotation doesn't have much extra DB impact, I take my original statement back. I can go with annotation as a solution. Okay with closing as duplicate of the various linked qns above. Thanks for the help everyone!